# Managing field values with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Typically, when I've created a form in react/redux myself, I have managed the inputs as 'controlled components', meaning when an input box changes, it calls a function that updates a variable that is fed back into the input. Of course, for me, this is the crux of redux, it's the flow.

However with redux-form, it seems I have no ability to do this on each of the fields. Almost as if, the fields are controlled, but within redux-form's own world, as far as I'm concerned they're not controlled as I'm not passing a value and re-acting to a change with a callback.

This is causing me a problem, as I may have something else that updates those input fields. For example a postcode lookup might update an address's fields. Before I transitioned to redux-form, the 'flow binding' meant I could update those fields from a different reducer as they essentially just represented a live slice of the redux store.

How do I get around this?

Edit: I think the best approach might be to use this https://redux-form.com/7.0.3/examples/selectingFormValues/, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Field values of redux forms can be modified using the reducer plugin. Basically you can add your own reducer to the one of redux form anf modify forms state like values, touched etc. Check it out here:
http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/ReducerPlugin.md/

Be aware is an advanced usage of redux and redux forms.